# Using pure CSS, is it possible to make a container's font-size proportional to its width or height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

To make font that always fits nicely in its container, I always use Javascript to make `div`s or a certain `class` have their `font-size` always equal to their `width` and have their inner text elements defined in terms that `font-size`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pjk8t5kb/

```
<div class="font-size-equals-width">
    <h1>Here's a headline</h1>
    <p>Here's some paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

---

```
.font-size-equals-width
{
    padding: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.font-size-equals-width h1 { font-size: 0.2em; }
.font-size-equals-width p { font-size: 0.1em; }
```

---

```
function scaleFontSize ( ) 
{
   $('.font-size-equals-width').each(function()
   { 
       var thisContainer = $(this); 
       thisContainer.css('font-size', thisContainer.width().toString() + 'px');
   });    
}

$(window).resize(function ( ) 
{
    scaleFontSize();       
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    scaleFontSize();   
});
```

---

My question is whether this is possible in CSS? From what I can tell, the only `font-size` units are `%`, `em`, `pt` and `px`, none of which are connected to container `width` or `height`. Does Bootstrap have anything for this? (I always include Bootstrap in my project but I have a feeling that I under-utilize it.)

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that ought to be achievable with [the calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), but sadly I don't think it's possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Try my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJBdxP

```
.font-size-equals-width {
  padding: 5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.font-size-equals-width h1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.font-size-equals-width p {
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

Try this

Hope it helps

Comment: To elaborate: `vw` stands for `viewport width`. See this for more info: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want Viewport Percentage Units: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Previously answered here: [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)